# How to find the Least Positive Residue?

Tags: number-theory

Say I want to find the least positive residue of 99 mod 28..

How would I go about this?

I've been staring at my book for a bit and I don't know how to apply the theorem to answer this question.

Comment: Just do the division  $99 = 28\times 3+15\implies 99\equiv 15 \pmod {28}$.

Comment: lulu i see what you did but can you elaborate on why thats the least positive residue?

Comment: That's the definition of the remainder in the division algorithm..if you divide $a$ by $b$ you write $a=b\times q + r$ where $0≤r<b$ .